# XSL - Do I need a Value-of?

Tags: xml, xslt, select, svg, value-of

```
<xsl:for-each select="/date/logs">

        <rect>

        <xsl:attribute name="fill">
        red
        </xsl:attribute>
```

.........
This is a portion of my XSL transformation document. When I process it, the red comes out as
just

```
&#10;&#9;&#9;red&#10;&#9;&#9;
```

Do I need a value-of select and a variable. I'm not that knowledgeable so sorry for my poor explanation.

Could Someone Help me Please,
Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use literal result elements including attribute values e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/date/logs">
  <rect fill="red"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If you want or need to populate an attribute value based on a value in your input doc use an attribute value template e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/date/logs">
  <rect fill="{@color}"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've now realised the problem was that I had line breaks/spaces.
Solved now.

Comment: To remedy that, you can use `<xsl:text>red</xsl:text>` and still format the XSLT nicely.